Too many inodes in /var/lib/apache2/fcgid/sock
In my Ubuntu 22.04 system, with apache 2.4.52 running, Apache2 is generating too many inodes:
root@m1:/var/lib/apache2/fcgid/sock# ls | wc -l
816320

I'd like to ask whether it is safe to rm these files in the /var/lib/apache2/fcgid/sock folder?
If not, what can I do to remove those files?
Thank you.
